# Change account associated with GoogleAppEngineLauncher

Tags: macos, google-app-engine

How do I change the Google Account associated with GoogleAppEngineLauncher.  I cannot find anywhere to change user or sign out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best/recommended way, but this is what worked for me:

bash: `rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.GoogleAppEngineLauncher.plist`

Then in GoogleAppEngineLauncher window, remove all projects, add a new project, then log into the desired account at the sign in window.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone still using the the launcher -

```
appcfg.py --no_cookies update <your app dir>
```

This should prompt you to login. Pick the google account of choice.